Calculating if cell proportions are significant using propeller
I am using propeller,https://rdrr.io/github/Oshlack/speckle/man/propeller.anova.html, to calculate significance between cell proportions in hypertrophy vs. control. My model is designed like this.
design <- model.matrix(~0 + grp + md_subset$batch)

I understand not setting an intercept to not have a baseline level and all categorical variables to be represented as separate column. So altogether I have 10 samples, 3 controls and 7 hypertrophy and they were done in 4 batches. My design matrix looks like this:

I have a couple of questions regarding the design matrix. One, why do not I have just 2 columns in the design matrix, one column for condition, whether control represented by 0 for that row and 1 representing hypertrophy, and one column for batch, represented by 1,2,3 or 4 in the rows as their are 4 batches? What I see is each condition has its own column and so does each batch. Looks to me like hot encoding but why is that necessary in this case? Second, if hot encoding is what is necessary and that is the reason each variable has a separate column, then why is batch 1 column not present as my sample 3 (row 3) is batch 1? Would this design matrix not take into account batch 1 effects?
Lastly, when I run this, i get an out put like this:
propeller.anova(prop.transformed, design=design, coef=c(1,2,3,4,5), robust=TRUE,
  trend=FALSE, sort=TRUE)



First, does running this with the design signify that I am looking at how proportion of each cell type between conditions is significant controlling for batch effects? The reason I ask this is because normally in regression, from my understanding, is the first variable after ~ is the variable you are testing and any additional variables are confounders you want to control for. However, in packages like DESeq2 or edgeR I have seen confounders controlled for occur first and the last variable is the variable you are testing how the response variable is related to. Also, does the p value and F statistic here show how much of an affect does the condition play on proportion and if it is significant? And each column labeled PropMean.* signify the coefficients for that variable for the different cell types?
I appreciate any help and clarification as I think I mainly understand but would like some help and advice.

Your question could do with more focus (or direct consultation) but the answer to most of it is "because you asked for it like that". You removed the overall intercept, hence not just one dummy for the extra condition. Batch is a factor, hence (k-1) dummies rather than a single "slope". The reference of any categorical variable is absorbed in its main intercept. Lastly, order of variables mattering depends on specific implementations and tests (e.g. type I vs. type III SS), any decent regression tool will let you specify any valid contrast. edgeR simply picks a default that you can change.

Hi, Thank you for editing the post. I understand code being in the quotation marks but the rest seems ok to me. Clicking on the images, I am able to see them clearly. Let me know if I have missed anything and will adjust. Sorry for my ignorance.

Some of us who have lived beyond normal retirement age have trouble seeing those images clearly, even when opened separately in a new window and blown up. It would help if you could at least put the R code and output into text form instead.

Hi EdM, sorry for the trouble. I tried putting the output as a text but the table gets messy. I have put the output as an excel table and attached an image. Hope that helps. Again, I am truly sorry for not being able to put this in a better format

As @PBulls noted in a comment, what you see is what you asked for.
When there's an intercept, the order of predictor variables doesn't matter for setting up the model (although it can for some types of post-modeling analysis). As you are learning, omitting an intercept (as evidently required by the propeller.anova() function) can be tricky.
Your observation:

normally in regression, from my understanding, is the first variable after ~ is the variable you are testing and any additional variables are confounders you want to control for

is the case when you remove the intercept. Then, if the first predictor is categorical, you will get separate coefficients for all its levels, providing separate outcome estimates for each of the levels.
If you remove the intercept, however, once you get beyond that first predictor variable the software still has to set up all the subsequent predictors as usual, with treatment coding the default in R. Otherwise the system is under-determined and would have an infinite number of possible solutions. Without an intercept, after treatment encoding of the later predictors, the coefficients of the first predictor represent the estimated outcome values at the reference levels of the other predictors. Coefficients for other levels of the later predictors are corresponding differences in outcome estimates.
In your case, what that means is that the values reported for PropMean.grpcontroland PropMean.grphypertrophy are estimates of what the cell-type proportions would be for the reference level of batch, evidently batch1. The coefficients for the other levels of batch are the differences estimated for each of the other batches from batch1 for each of the cell-type proportions.
What you want is something that compares PropMean.grpcontrol versus PropMean.grphypertrophy in a way that combines information properly from all the batches. I'm not sure just what the propeller.anova() F-statistics and p-values represent, but I suspect that they are not what you need. Check the documentation; the software might be treating all 5 columns as separate categorizations or treatments, which doesn't represent your situation.
You would probably be better off dealing with batch differences at an earlier stage of the analysis and then use the combined results afterward, for example using the Bioconductor sva package to correct for batch effects first.

Thank you so much EdM, this was very insightful and helpful in making this much more clear to me. Will read the documentation over and see if I can find a way. Otherwise, will try to model the batch effect on the proportions using a generalized linear model. Thank you for your help.
